# ios stuck at an exception while subclassing uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, key-value-coding

I am trying to build a custom cell for UITableview. The approach I have taken is

- Subclassed the `UITableViewCell` and created my own custom class which has members for UI components (Labels, images etc)
- Created a nib and changed its class to my custom class.

Here is the code of my class

**Header file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ActivePoolViewCustomCell : UITableViewCell{
    UILabel* lblDate;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel* lblDate;
@end
```

**Implementation file**

```
#import "ActivePoolViewCustomCell.h"

@implementation ActivePoolViewCustomCell
@synthesize lblDate;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Then I created a nib and changed its class to ActivePoolViewCustomCell and connected a UILabel to the lblDate outlet.

Now, the problem I face is, when I execute the following code to load the nib

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ActivePoolCell";

    ActivePoolViewCustomCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActivePoolViewCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = (ActivePoolViewCustomCell*)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.lblDate.text = @"abcd";
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I get the following error

2012-10-30 18:13:56.451 Cda[637:f803] *** **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lblDate.'**

After a lot of struggle, I am unable to comprehend the cause of this problem. What is the problem here ? or the concept itself is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sorted it out. The problem was, I was applying the ActivePoolViewCustomCell class to the files owner of my custom cell nib which I should have been applying to the cell itself.

this video helped me out to resolve it

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_kO-J3DYvc